# Erro em mysqli: "expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given"

Tags: php, mysql

Está dando esse erro:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in

Meu código é esse:

```
define("HOST", "localhost");
define("USER", "meu-usuario");
define("PASS", "minha-senha");
define("BDNAME", "meu_banco_de_dados");

mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS);
mysqli_select_db(BDNAME)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo a documentação da função [`mysqli_select_db`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.select-db.php), é necessário passar dois parâmetros para esta função, sendo o primeiro o *connection link* e o segundo o nome da *database*.

**Edit**

> Connection link é um recurso retornado por mysqli_connect() ou mysqli_init()

Exemplo:

```
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS);
mysqli_select_db($con, BDNAME);
```

Answer (score 2):

Deveria ter dois parâmetros para conectar assim:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Checa a database
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Deu errado mano: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$teste = "Select * from table";

// Change database to "teste "
mysqli_select_db($con,"teste ");

// ...some PHP code for database "test"...

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

ou via Objeto assim:

```
<?php
// Aqui você se conecta ao banco
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb');
// Executa uma consulta que pega cinco notícias
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `titulo` FROM `noticias` LIMIT 5";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($dados = $query->mysqli_fetch_array()) {
  echo 'ID: ' . $dados['id'] . '';
  echo 'Título: ' . $dados['titulo'] . '';
}
echo 'Registros encontrados: ' . $query->num_rows;
```

Bom somente para informação acadêmica esse método foi descontinuado nas versões antigas de php.

Comment: valeu pela ajuda !!